# How to install tools for everyone to use in unix

Tags: unix

I'm a freshman, and I created a server with my roomates in order to practice in maintaining a server.

We installed CentOS7. And I would like to ask how I can install a tool for everyone to use?

More particularly, we want to install [Cromwell](https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell#website-and-user-guide). But since, they don't have instructions on how to install on Unix, I downloaded [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/) and installed it like this.

The downside is that it's not `visible` to the other users connected to the servers.

I know this is a noob question, but any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A standard unix machine has programs (tools and so on) installed in predefined directories like /bin, /usr/bin, perhaps /usr/local/bin. Which to choose is another matter, probably you want /usr/bin. Also the environ variable PATH plays a role.

Into the chosen directory there should be a file representing the "tool". You can put a copy of the executable file in that directory, and set (or check) its permissions. Execution permission can be granted to all users, or only some, it depends. In other words,

> /home/me/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cromwell

is not a good place for a "system" tool or app; you should copy that executable in /usr/bin, set ownership (perhaps to root?) with chown, and set the correct permissions with chmod.

You can make a hard link of your executable into the directory; this saves space, but also means that there is only one copy of the executable. Having two different copies (the "stable" one, and the other one you can fiddle with) can be handy.

After the executable is reachable and executable from the chosen users, maybe it needs some support files. To find them, it can rely on fixed locations, or some environment variable, or some configuration file. But all these things are outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
you@machine$ sudo chmod [who][op][permissions] filename
```

"who" refers to the users that have a particular permission: the user ("u"), the group ("g"), or other users ("o", also known as "world"). "op" determines whether to add ("+"), remove ("-") or explicitly set ("=") the particular permissions. "permissions" are whether the file should be readable ("r"), writable ("w"), or executable ("x"). As an example:

```
you@machine$ chmod o+x file
```

will add executable permission for others to file.

Comment: so, the program is installed in `/home/me/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cromwell` so, I should do `sudo chmod o+x cromwell` and everybody will be able to run it? like `gcc`?

Comment: if they have access to this file then yes, give it a try.

Comment: it's not a file. It's an executable. Ultimately, I want any user to type `cromwell [parameter]`. Like `gcc`

Comment: Executable is also a file, that performs some encoded instructions, opposed to data file. Just try doing what I wrote in my answer.

`sudo chmod o+x /home/me/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cromwell`